# PHP Nested Loop with count

Tags: php, loops

I can see a few ways of doing this and please bear with me as I am new to PHP.

I have a list of items that I want to print onto labels, the label sheets have 8 printable labels so I need a loop to collect all the items and add a page break after 8 labels:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= 8) {            
        Repeat this for 8 labels                   
    }
}
```

Now after 8 items I need to add a page break

So I was going to put a nested loop with a count inside and increment but I don't know if this is the best way?

I am basically asking what's the best way to approach this as there could be thousands of items so would like it to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add $i++   inside the  end of loop

Comment: Thanks, sorry missed that.

Comment: no problum can you vote for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$j = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $j++;
    if($j%8 == 0) {
        echo "Repeat label for 8 record<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a `for` loop and modulus?

```
<?php
    $everyNth = 32;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1234; $i++) {
        if ($i > 0 && !($i % $everyNth)) {
            echo $i . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
?>
```

Prints:

```
32
64
96
128
160
192
224
256
288
320
352
384
416
448
480
512
544
576
608
640
672
704
736
768
800
832
864
896
928
960
992
1024
1056
1088
1120
1152
1184
1216
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/3Vu0ePrc)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$items = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$i = 1;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item." ";
    if ($i === 8) {
        echo "<br />";
        $i = 0;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$j = 0;
for($i=0;$i<40;$i++) {
    $j++;
    if($j%8 == 0) {
        echo "Repeat label for 8 record<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

This is simple example.